# How can I change the axis name in a ggplot2 facet-grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using GGplot2 to create the following plot

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data=emodata, aes(x=trueSNR, y=score, colour=factor(Task)))
plot1 + stat_smooth(method="lm")+ facet_grid(. ~ Condition_f)
```

[image]

I'm trying to change the default axes names (y = "score" to be "proportion correct", x="trueSNR" to be "dB SNR"). By default they get the variable name in the dataframe. This seems like something that should be really easy, but I can't find a question here that answers it (most seem like they discuss re-labelling the axis, which seems problematic when using facet_grid). The primary issue is trying to edit axis labels from within the facet_grid arguments.

Anyway, I know this may be trivial, but I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: See the `labs()` or `ylab()` function

Comment: @benson23 yes, that answers it - the solutions here feel more clear to me so I'd like to keep this a separate question. I updated the question to clarify that the question is whetehr or not you can change axis labels using the facet_grid function, which it appears you cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the axes names similar to any other ggplot plot. One way of doing this is with the labs function:

`plot1 + labs(x = "proportion correct", y = "dB SNR")`

The labs can be added before or after the facet_grid and both work. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `labs()`:

```
plot1 + stat_smooth(method="lm")+ facet_grid(. ~ Condition_f) +
 labs(x="trueSNR", y="proportion correct")
```